# Oracle timestamp datatype is missing time information

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to store a datetime value in oracle from .net and when the date time gets persisted to the db, the time information is missing.

The db is 11g and I'm using the OracleCommand and OracleConnection classes from the Oracle.DataAccess assembly version 2.111.6.20.

I have a data layer in .net which calls an oracle stored procedure. The parameter for the datefield in question is an IN parameter which is marks as a TimeStamp datatype. The field in the table is also defined as a TimeStamp.

```
// Add the parameter to the OracleCommand
var dt = new DateTime(2011,07,07,10,0,0);
cmd.Parameters.Add("RECEIVED", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, 6, dt, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The value of the parameter does contain the time information (10am), but when it gets persisted to the db, the time info is missing.

My stored procedure looks something like this...

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DATA_INSERT 
(
  ID OUT NUMBER
, RECEIVED IN TIMESTAMP
) AS 
BEGIN

  ID := MY_SEQUENCE.nextval;
  INSERT INTO DATA (ID, RECEIVED) VALUES (ID, RECEIVED);

END DATA_INSERT;
```

Any idea why the timestamp is losing the time information?

Comment: @kevincline, column datatype is TimeStamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out what the issue is. In the example above I omitted some additional parameters from my stored proc for berevity. I have other parameters in the query, some of which are of datatype DATE. So, consider the following table...

```
  CREATE TABLE TEST (DATE_FIELD DATE, TIMESTAMP_FIELD TIMESTAMP);
```

And the stored procedure...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT ( P_DATE IN DATE, P_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP ) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST(DATE_FIELD, TIMESTAMP_FIELD) VALUES(P_DATE, P_TIMESTAMP);
END TEST_INSERT;
```

And the following c#...

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("TEST_INSERT", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp
        , new DateTime(2011, 07, 07, 10, 0, 0), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DATE", OracleDbType.Date
        , new DateTime(2011, 07, 08), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The result will be...

```
DATE_FIELD: 11-07-07 
TIMESTAMP_FIELD: 11-07-08 00:00:00.000000000
```

So, even though the parameters are named, it seems as though the name of the parameter is irrelevant and that the order in which parameters are added to the Parameters collection in .net will determine the values of the parameters in the stored procedure.

So, in the c# snippet if you reverse the order in which the parameters are added to the collection to...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DATE", OracleDbType.Date
     , new DateTime(2011, 07, 08), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp
     , new DateTime(2011, 07, 07, 10, 0, 0), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
```

then the result will be...

```
DATE_FIELD: 11-07-08 
TIMESTAMP_FIELD: 11-07-07 10:00:000000000
```

Comment: DateField can hold time to SECOND as well, the timestamp can hold fractional seconds, so you may not need the timestamp unless you need the precision provided by that.

Comment: ah, very good to know @Harrison. My assumption was that it was just the date, but this was because I had the parameters reversed and the field where I expected time information only had date info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Regarding the order of parameters issue, you need to set `cmd.BindByName = true`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/CommandBindByName.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you issue this select, what do you see:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(RECEIVED, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM data WHERE ID = <value>;
```

Comment: the result of that query is 07/07/2011 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code into a table and my results were (07-JUL-11 10.00.00.000000000 AM ) which is what is expected.  I see that you are using the same name for the column and parameter, try pre-pending a "p_" infront of the variable name and see if it works

this is what I ran:
In Oracle:

```
 create table t_data(received timestamp);
```

in c#

```
  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("BEGIN INSERT INTO t_DATA (RECEIVED) VALUES (:RECEIVED); END;",con);
        // Add the parameter to the OracleCommand
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011,07,07,10,0,0);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("RECEIVED", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, 6, dt, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

back to Oracle

```
   select * from t_data            

RECEIVED                  
------------------------- 
07-JUL-11 10.00.00.000000000 AM
```

If anything, try something like this to see if it works then go back and check your procedure and see if something doesn't look awry (like a wayward trunc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Oracle provided dll, it binds variables ordinally by default. Add the following line of code before you execute to bind to the names.

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```